# Remove multiple tasks from scheduling queue

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, scheduled-tasks, distributed-computing, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to schedule and run tasks in parallel in a multi-node distributed memory cluster.

I have many different tasks which have dependencies on other tasks, but I also want to run the same tasks in parallel with different parameters.
For example, say I have a task which has a desired optimal parameter of 10 but there is a chance that this might fail (due to certain complexities within the specific task - which cannot be known beforehand). To hedge the risk of failure I also want to run the same task with the next best parameter. To continue hedging risk, I want to run even more tasks with decreasing next best parameters.

There is an implied hierarchy amongst the tasks based upon the optimal parameter. All tasks with a lesser optimal parameter can be considered hedges to the better value.

My main question is:
Since I'm running the same tasks in parallel with different parameters, and the tasks, based on the optimality of the parameter, are prioritized in the sense that as soon as any instance of that task completes successfully, I want to kill all subsequent instances of the task which have lower priority (have worse parameters) and remove them from the process queue.
In other words, I want to kill off the hedge processes when I know that a better parameter task has completed successfully.

Does [DAGuE](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/dague/overview/index.html) allow this? i.e. the removal of tasks from the queue? If not, can another C++ scheduler be suggested.

Comment: Concerning DAGuE I would suggest you to ask that question to one of the project members as it might be too specific.

Comment: @ bacchus, thanks for responding. Actually, I was hoping for any suggestions, and it doesn't have to be using DAGuE. My main requirement here is that I need to be able to remove tasks from the queue for the above implementation.